# Jar file not running properly after building in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jar, netbeans-7, executable-jar

I have made a project and when i run it through net beans it runs properly means my log in screen appears and when i enter my id and password it opens next screen....but when i run it using .jar file it is opening login file but when i enter (valid) id and password it is not opening next window. It is blocking log in buton which means it is loading but after some time it is not showing me next screen. If i build or run it using net beans it is not showing a single problem..here is my build out put

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\IDocCsMain run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IDocCsMain\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
 Updating property file:C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IDocCsMain\build\built-jar.properties
```

compile:

Comment: when you say it does not work, are you getting any errors? also, have you checked your classpath, to make sure everything netbeans uses (other projects/jars/libraries), is also available and used by your jar when used as "standalone"?

Comment: Seems you need to do a bit of logging or other debugging to wee what is happening.  Make sure that ***every*** `catch (Exception e)` has a `e.printStackTrace();`  As an experiment, launch the Jar from the command line using something like `java -jar the.jar` to see what output it produces.

Comment: When is is blocked, take a thread dump to see why it is blocked

Comment: @acostache: no it is not showing any error...It does't do anything.

Comment: @HaseebWali  *"it is not showing any error"*  Answer these specific questions. 1) Have you ensured every `catch` has a `printStackTrace()`? 2) What happened when you ran it from the command line?

Comment: Let me try your opinions and than comment back..

Comment: I am not sure who you are replying to (add @PersonName to notify them), but note that so far I have offered advice, not opinions.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sure sir you are giving advises sorry for my bad english..and i ran .jar from command line it showing error of not setting icon properly.. thanks a lot Andrew Thompson you gave me life back.....

Comment: *"it showing error of not setting icon properly.. "*  So you solved it?  If so, you should describe how in an answer, and accept the answer.  *"thanks a lot Andrew Thompson you gave me life back.."*  Glad to help, but let's not get all mushy here.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: as soon as i solve the problem i will answer it here.

Comment: 5/10/2013 This must be a new issue in NetBeans or something. I got the same issue but working with a long standing project, on version 13++ now. Working fine on the build on all previous versions in netbeans, dist/jar file, but the new one I just created, the path isn't set right...... I even did a copy project in netbeans, create new project and copy class files over, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution i am writing by myself with the help of "Advise" given to me by "Andrew Thompson". I was getting an icon and setting it on JLabel in constructor. When, i was running it through net beans it was running perfectly but when i ran it without net beans, with .jar file it was not getting path of icon and showing throwing exception(checked it by running it in command prompt). I set my path dynamically and now it is running properly.